# Term Frequency and Document Frequency of words

Tags: python, nltk

I have written some code to find the term frequency and document frequency of words that contained in file stored at location path. Each file is go through the function `cleanDoc()` to get the words from text files and I want to file the term frequency in the tabled manner means so that all words from all documents should be considered to find count. Can anybody tell how should I implement it? I am only using NLTK.

```
import collections
import os.path
import glob
import nltk

wdict = set()

path = "C://Python27//Corpus Files//*.*"

#this function cleans up a doc (removes stopwords etc)
def cleanDoc(doc):
    stopset = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
    stemmer = nltk.PorterStemmer()
    tokens = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(doc)
    clean = [token.lower() for token in tokens if token.lower() not in stopset and len(token) > 3 and token.isalpha()]
    final = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in clean]
    return final

for text in glob.glob(path):

    f = open(text)
    data= f.read()
    words = cleanDoc(data)
    wdict.update(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FreqDist` object, from `nltk.probability` to count these words. Later, you can navigate in it using a dict-like key-value interface and methods (like `freq.items()` or `freq['word']`), or you can even plot the results using `matplotlib`.

```
import collections
import os.path
import glob
import nltk
from nltk.probability import FreqDist


term_frequency = {}

path = "C://Python27//Corpus Files//*.*"

#this function cleans up a doc (removes stopwords etc)
def cleanDoc(doc):
    stopset = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
    stemmer = nltk.PorterStemmer()
    tokens = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(doc)
    clean = [token.lower() for token in tokens if token.lower() not in stopset and len(token) > 3 and token.isalpha()]
    final = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in clean]
    return final

for text in glob.glob(path):
    f = open(text)
    data = f.read()
    words = cleanDoc(data)
    numbers_of_words = len(words)
    freq = FreqDist(all_words)
    # term_frequency is a dict which structure is like:
    # {
    #     'path_to_file': 
    #         {'term': 13.4, 'another_term': 15}, 
    #     'another_file': 
    #         {'term2': 12, 'foo': 15}
    #  } 
    for term in freq.keys():
        if isintance(term_frequency[text], dict):
            term_frequency[text][term] = freq[term]/numbers_of_words
        else:
            term_frequency[text] = {term: freq[term]/numbers_of_words}
```

Reference: https://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.probability.FreqDist-class.html

Comment: It does not consider all words from all documents saved at path. I got result for only few terms.

Comment: My bad, gonna fix it now.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work. I want count for words with reference to that document.

Comment: I didn't get it. You said you wanted to get the term frequency of all the words in all those documents.

Comment: Term frequency = (Number of times term t appears in a document) / (Total number of terms in the document).

Comment: Just create a `FreqDist` for each document and calculate it, it's simple. I'm gonna modify the snippet for you.

Comment: No, "term frequency" is simply the number of times term t occurs in document d. The formula you gave is known as tf*idf where "tf" (obviously) stands for "term frequency".

Comment: @DummyGuy can't you use my code as a base to do what you want? I'm not clearly understanding what you really want, but it can't be that hard to achieve from this code.